# Do long answers decrease the question-to-answer upvote ratio?

Tags: support, voting, statistics

I noticed that on highly voted questions, some questions have half as many upvotes as their accepted answers, while others have just as many. The ratio is usually 1:1 or 1:2 (in favor of the answer) - but rarely something like 2:3.

I then noticed that the way I upvote is I usually first read the question, then the answer, then finally upvote. If both are short (like 1-2 paragraphs) then it's an easy 2 clicks with little mouse movement and I upvote both. But if the answer is a page long and the question is outside of the page, 
I will need to scroll up to upvote the question, then I'm much less likely to do it just because it's not ergonomic.

I'm wondering if I'm just imagining this or if there really is a correlation between answer length and upvote ratio - in particular a sharp drop-off at the answer-length that would make the question be outside of the screen by the time you've read the answer.

Comment: it's likely more than just the fact that the voting ui is out of view. such as the usefulness of the answer.

Comment: This question is clearly about Stack Overflow and the software that powers it, so it's definitely on-topic here. As such, I've re-opened it. The answer will probably involve someone putting together a SEDE query that obtains the desired data. Even if nobody wants to bother with doing that, it doesn't make the question off-topic.

Comment: Regardless of what the answers say, I think it would be cool to add a feature making the voting buttons fixed to the left of each question and answer so the voting buttons always show as you scroll a long question or answer.

Comment: @KodosJohnson They tried that once (sticky-scrolling vote buttons) and people _hated_ them.

Comment: The way I upvote is search for a topic in Google. If the SO question title remotely resembles my question, I upvote it. Then I scroll down. If one or more of the answers solve my problem or give me greater insight into it, then I upvote them, too. The length of the answers don't really affect whether I vote for the question or not. I'm just sharing this to show a different voting pattern than yours.

Comment: @KodosJohnson for reference: [A/B testing the sticky vote controls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258048/295232)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've constructed the following [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/726985/average-ratio-of-q-vs-a-score-depending-on-answer-length?IntervalLength=50&MaximumLength=5000#graph), based on an earlier [answer on Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26281/228959). It shows you, for accepted answers with a score > 0, the ratio of the score of the question and the score of the answer. (This is something else than the # of upvotes, but I couldn't get that to work. I'm sure there are people here who can.) You see that for longer answers, the ratio becomes higher, which means the question gets upvoted more. There's no notable sharp drop-off, even if you increase the maximum length; also, a page long answer has a different number of characters depending on e.g your computer and the presence of pictures.

[image]

Interestingly, if you look at the [absolute numbers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/726987/average-answer-score-depending-on-answer-length?IntervalLength=50&MaximumLength=5000#graph), you see that there is a small dip around ±300 characters, so writing longer answers than that can still be beneficial (statistically speaking).

[image]

Comment: Does this include the questions older than 2008 (or whatever the year was when the rules of SO changed significantly)? If so, can we have a result without those old-style questions and answers?

Comment: @ThomasWeller yes. I'm not sure if the rules changed, or just the way they were enforced; also, SO was launched in 2008. Feel free to [fork the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/726985) and see if the results change if you introduce an additional filter `q.CreationDate >= '2010-01-01'` or something similar.